# How to generate random position object

Tags: processing

I'm trying to generate 15 circles on a 1500 - 1000 space, every cirlce with a diferent position. I know how to generate 1 random circle but that's all. How should I do it?

Comment: You have to be more specific. I guess you want to create 15 not intersecting circles? Note, 2 circles are intersecting, if the distances between the center points is less then the sum of the radii.

Comment: Just 15 circles randomly located on the screen, doesen't matter the distance between them.

Comment: So what is the question? Are you searching for [Array](https://processing.org/reference/Array.html)s?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're looking for a `for` loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 15; i++){
  // draw a random circle here
}
```

Shameless self-promotion: [here](https://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/for-loops) is a tutorial on `for` loops in Processing.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you need to create a Circle class and ArrayList which contains all your circles.
Then using a `for` you add in that list 15 circles passing to constructor random coordinates and a fixed width and height you decide.

```
class Circle {
    float x, y, size;

    public Circle(float x, float y, float size) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.size = size;
    }

    public void update() {
        ellipse(x, y, size, size);
    }
}
```

Declare globally your ArrayList. Now, in `setup()` you instantiate your ArrayList and populate it with randomly generated coordinates

```
ArrayList<Circle> circlesList; // This needs to be declared globally
float circleSize = 64; // Circles size in pixels

void setup() {
    size(1500, 1000);

    circlesList = new ArrayList<Circle>();

    // Populating the ArrayList with circles
    for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
        float randomx = random(0, 1500); // Random generated X
        float randomy = random(0, 1000); // Random generated Y
        Circle newCircle = new Circle(randomx, randomy, circleSize);

        circlesList.add(newCircle);
    }
}
```

Now in `draw()` function, using a foreach loop, you'll draw every single circle inside that ArrayList

```
void draw() {
    background(255); // Background color

    fill(255, 0, 0); // Circle fill color
    for (Circle c : circlesList) {
        c.update();
    }
}
```

Please note that this way your circles may overlap or be a little bit outside of the screen. Ask anything if the code is unclear, don't just copy-paste it.

Hope this helped :)